# How can I connect BNB Smartchain testnet with Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

In the UI, I can only see BNB Smartchain mainnet, If I want to deploy my contract and use Gnosis Safe on BNB Testnet, How can I do it?

Comment: Last thing I remember:  it does not support Test BSC, only BSC. If you want to test it on test Blockchain, you need to use ethereum test nets

Comment: I see, thanks for information so it sounds like I need Rinkeby testnet instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Gnosis does not support officially BNB testnet you have to set up the infrastructure and the UI yourself. For that you need `docker compose` and a BNB RPC address: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-infrastructure